# My electric oven runs 200C too hot. What can I do?

Tags: electrical, repair, kitchens, oven

I have a fairly new (2011-ish) electric oven by Amica which has been running about 200 °C too hot. I can't find a thing in the manuals about re-calibration, though I have read in the past that it's possible to calibrate it without having to call in the troops for repair.

What should I be looking for? Or, is this something that simply should be handled by the pros?

Comment: 200 C? That's pretty much the entire usable range of the oven... if you set it to 200 do you know it's actually 400 C? That is DANGEROUSLY hot (which is why cleaning cycles normally lock the oven door). I'd get this sorted ASAP.

Comment: How are you measuring the temperature? Cheap bimetallic oven thermometers can be very inaccurate.

Comment: What is the model number?  Could it be that the oven is actually calibrated in °F?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the thermostat or given that this company seems to make entirely digital ovens the temperature sensor.  I think you need to get the oven serviced by a professional.

Comment: Are you sure the oven is set for Celsius and not Fahrenheit.  350 F ~ 170 C, close to you 200 degree difference.

Comment: I think @diceless has this figured out.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest searching the web for Amica maintenance instructions for your model. If there are recalibrations available at all, that's where you'll find the instructions.

Normally, a service tech would just swap out the electronics and/or sensor, since if it's drifted this far there's no guarantee that it won't do other Bad Things some time soon.

Comment: If you really want to take a stab at it, I'd try replacing the thermostat first. Usually if you remove the back panel of your oven you will see an incredibly good wiring diagram (I know this is true for GE/Whirlpool/Kenmore). Trace it out and replace the thermostat. Usually the electronics are all sold as a single modular unit, and it will cost half to 2/3rds of the price of a new oven (ours cost ~$240). The upside is they're incredibly easy to replace, usually you'll just have to crimp on some shielded quick disconnects to leads and plug them in.

Service tech is the safest option.